# Can't find option "local terminal" (Settings -> System -> Developer options) in android one

Tags: android, terminal, android-8.1-oreo

I want to enable terminal on my android phone. (I have phone Xiomi Mi A1 with OS "Android one").

I enabled "Developer options" (by pressing several time on "Build number" item in settings). Settings appeared - but there is no item "Local terminal".

One more strange thing: after I enabled "Developer options" - in search results, in settings - appeared result "Local terminal" when I type "terminal" - but it navigate me only to System -> Developer options... And there is no such option - "Local terminal".

Why? And what to do?

Comment: _"And what to do?"_ Install one of the many terminal emulators from the Google Play store?

Comment: @Michael l don't need any emulator. I need terminal.

Comment: No, you need a _terminal emulator_. And there are several of them on the Google Play store.

Comment: I suggest,  that you are a developer of one of them... So , dear friend, please read further sentences carefully: "I do not need any emulators and similar rubbish. I need access to the terminal of Linux kernel. If you can not help - please, sit quietly. Stack overflow is not a right place for stupid marketing." @Michael

Comment: _"I suggest, that you are a developer of one of them."_ I am not. I'll quote from an answer to another question: _"A **terminal emulator** is a program that emulates a physical terminal (e.g. xterm, gnome-terminal, minicom).
So when you look to a "text window" on your linux system (under X11) you are looking to: a terminal emulator, connected to a virtual terminal, identified by a tty file, inside which runs a shell."_ That sounds like exactly what you're looking for. If it isn't, please update your question with more details.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen, or heard of, a "Local terminal" in Developer options. Where have you seen this?

Comment: Hi, @MikeM. Proof, that setting existed (check source code on github):
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/search?q=local+terminal&unscoped_q=local+terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer on issue tracker of Android OS. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111569269

That setting ("Local terminal") existed in fact, but wasn't supported for a long time. There is only a leftover - bug, that I found in "Search settings". I received an answer from dev team, that it was fixed already - but in version 8.1 - it is still there.

Proof, that setting existed (check source code on github):
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/search?q=local+terminal&unscoped_q=local+terminal

Comment: in-code the setting is still around, but you need the package `com.android.terminal` installed / built with the image for the enable_terminal option to show up

Comment: Indeed, `com.android.terminal` does [still exist in the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Terminal/+/refs/heads/main/src/com/android/terminal/Terminal.java)